# univariate bracketing root finding method that uses derivatives

Tags: numerical-methods, roots

Consider a continuously differentiable function $f: [a_0, b_0] \to \mathbb{R}$, where the derivative $f'(x)$ is available at negligible extra cost, and $\text{sign}(f(a_0) = -\text{sign}(f(b_0))$.

Is there a robust, bracketing-style algorithm to that makes use of the derivative for finding a root $f(x) \approx 0$?

What I have seen are "safe" variants of Newton's method that fall back to bisection etc based on some *ad-hoc* criteria. But I could not find a detailed convergence analysis of these.

I imagine that given a bracket, $f'(a_i)$ and $f'(b_i)$ could be used to improve the interpolation of (the inverse of) $f$ on the interval.

Comment: In what circumstances do you imagine the derivative has negligible cost, and not cost close to the evaluation cost of the function itself?

Comment: Eg solving $x = \int_a^y g(z) dz$ for $y$ given $x, a, g$.